# Stopping but not killing a process in the powershell/cmd

Tags: process, cmd

I'm just done with a Bash mini-project, and I'm wondering if the Bash commands:

```
kill -stop

kill -cont
```

which pause and continue the process (but don't terminate it) are available in the Windows environment.

Comment: of course i've found the downloadable tools like psSuspend etc., and the option of suspending each thread in a process, but it's hard to believe there is no base counterpart

Comment: If you install Services for Unix (Control Panel - Programs and Features) you can have Korn and C shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NTSD which is installed on Pro versions. It's a debugger, you can stop any program.

```
ntsd -pn notepad.exe
```

Type g to make it go. F12 to break.